# Make a Popup/Alert Window in a html with a "dont show again" option

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I am trying to make a popup / alert window so that when the page is being loaded, the popup will open. I searched around and found something I like, but I don't know how to get this option working with the ability to not show the popup to the user more than once (with a "Don't show this again" option).

I added this to my header in the script part:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ alert('hi')});
```

I know that I need the jQuery script for this, so I added

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to my HTML page. This is working fine, but I don't know how I could modify my alert in a way for making a checkbox or a button with "Don't show this again".

I also found a solution where the alert was an external popup HTML page, but I want it inside my HTML page. Is there a way to solve my problem over that, or is the way over the alarm better?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't do this through a typical JavaScript alert box. You'll need to build you own modal popup to simulate an alert box. jQuery's plugin [**jQuery UI**](https://jqueryui.com/) has a really nice built-in function for this, and I'll use this in my example.

To give the user the option of not showing a window again, you need to make use of [**localStorage**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). You would need to create a condition that checks for whether a localStorage item is set. If it is not, display the modal, if it is, hide the modal:

```
if (!localStorage.hideAlert) {
  $(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog();
  });
}
else {
  $("#dialog").css("display", "none");
}
```

In the modal itself, you would have a 'No' button that adds the relevant value to localStorage:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Show Again?">
  <p>Would you like to show this dialog again?</p>
  <button name="yes" class="yes">Yes</button>
  <button name="no" class="no">No</button>
</div>

$(".yes").on("click", function() {
  $("#dialog").dialog("close");
});
$(".no").on("click", function() {
  localStorage.setItem('hideAlert', true);
  $("#dialog").dialog("close");
});
```

I've created a working example showcasing this [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/h5q7pe3m/1/).

This way, all of your code can reside within a **single file**, though remember that you'll still need to include the external jQuery UI JavaScript, and optional CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I have a little problem adding this to a page which contains various of wrappers and types of maps , how can i decide to let this box appear all over every layer of that page?

Comment: You need to use `z-index`. Give the popup a high z-index to ensure it always rests on top of every other element :)

Answer (score 0):

In the example below, every popup window has a "Don't Show This Again" button.

Main document:

Code:

```
<HTML>
<Head>
<Script Language=JavaScript>

    var expDate = new Date();
    expDate.setTime(expDate.getTime()+365*24*60*60*1000); // one year

    function setCookie(isName,isValue,dExpires){

        document.cookie = isName+"="+isValue+";expires="+dExpires.toGMTString();
    }

    function getCookie(isName){

        cookieStr = document.cookie;
        startSlice = cookieStr.indexOf(isName+"=");
        if (startSlice == -1){return false}
        endSlice = cookieStr.indexOf(";",startSlice+1)
        if (endSlice == -1){endSlice = cookieStr.length}
        isData = cookieStr.substring(startSlice,endSlice)
        isValue = isData.substring(isData.indexOf("=")+1,isData.length);
        return isValue;
    }

    function initPopups(){

        if (!getCookie('pop1'))
        {popWin1 = window.open("1/pop1.html","","width=200,height=150,top=50,left=400")}
        if (!getCookie('pop2'))
        {popWin2 = window.open("1/pop2.html","","width=200,height=150,top=50,left=180")}
    }

    window.onload=initPopups;

</Script>
</Head>
<Body>


</Body>
```

The popup files are in a folder named 1

pop1.html:

Code:

```
<HTML>
   <Body>
      <input type=button value="Don't show again" onclick="opener.setCookie('pop1',0,opener.expDate);self.close()">
   </Body>
</HTML>
```

pop2.html:

Code:

```
<HTML>
   <Body>
      <input type=button value="Don't show again" onclick="opener.setCookie('pop2',0,opener.expDate);self.close()">
   </Body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Read my last sentence please :)

Comment: Oh, didn't see that